# adding adbannerview to bottom of ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to ad adbannerview in my ios application i have alredy added it for iPhone   which displays correctly at the bottom of the device but when i am trying to do the same for iPad  it displays in middle of the screen 
please help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use autolayouting from Interface Builder and keep the view for your 'Ad' to be Bottom aligned and thats pretty much it.No matter what device you want to support it always will come at the bottom.

Something like this :

[image]